# "Create local mock" quick fix

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, mockito

a few hours ago I managed to crash my complete Eclipse in such a way that I needed to reinstall it from scratch.
After a while I noticed that one cool feature is missing: It was a quick fix options for unit tests, like this:

[image]

Besides these 4 options, I had a fifth: "Create local mock" or similar. That option would've created in the images example the line

```
CatalogueArticle cataArticle = mock(CatalogueArticle.class);
```

I really miss this and I am not able to google this little feature ... came it with MoreUnit? (doesn't seem so as I use it already), did I write it myself (don't even know how, so I doubt that), can I check some preferences to enable it, ...)

I hope someone knows this feature and can tell me how to enable it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the plugin "Mockito Quick Fix Tools". You find it on the Marketplace.